# What's the difference between these sentences?

Tags: grammar

> He walked out, Rachel's words indelibly etched into his memory.

vs

> He walked out, Rachel's words being indelibly etched into his memory.

Comment: The second one contains the word *being*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we pick some slightly less awkward examples:

> He walked out, Rachel's words indelibly etched into his memory.

vs.

> He walked out, Rachel's words being indelibly etched into his memory.

Still awkward, but I think both are grammatical.

Grammatically, I can't tell you anything certain, as my copy of *CGEL* is in my other pants. So I will speculate. In both sentences, everything after the comma is a dependent clause that's a variation of “Rachel's words were indelibly etched into his memory”. The first sentence is similar to “He walked out, *his face red*” or “*his grey eyes flashing*” or “*the spell broken at last*” or “*the severed limbs of his enemies scattered behind him*”. This sort of dependent clause is definitely grammatical, but I don't know what it's called. The second sentence is just a slightly different variation of the same clause, but again, I don't know what kind.

Semantically, there is just a slight difference. The first sentence only says that he walked out *with* Rachel's words etched into his memory. The second suggests that he walked out *because* her words were etched into his memory.

**Update** – Yep, they're clauses. Here, according to *CGEL*, they're being used as supplements. That means they're not grammatically required or tightly grammatically integrated into the sentence like a subject or object. They're tacked on at the end.

Example 1 contains a verbless clause. A plain old subject + predicate clause with no verb can be the object of the preposition *with* (“His pants (were) around his ankles” → “He was caught with *his pants around his ankles*.”) or, sometimes, a supplement (“He stormed out, *his pants around his ankles*.”)

Example 2 contains an *-ing* clause (what *CGEL* calls a gerund-participial clause). These are most often used in places where noun phrases could be used (“*His death* was not part of the plan” → “*John being dead* was not part of the plan.”), and the subject of the *-ing* clause is usually omitted (“*Being dead* was not part of the plan.”), so your example is unusual. Still grammatical, though.

Comment: By the way, I've changed the original sentences into yours. Because obviously that's closer to what I intended to ask about.

Comment: Hope you find your grammar manual and complete your answer. Thanks.

Comment: OK, updated. Note that different grammars use different names for things. A "gerund-participial clause" is traditionally called a present participial phrase. The traditional terms are still the ones taught in school.

Answer (score 3):

Not to put too fine a point on it, but they're both rather awkward. I'd recast them this way:

> He walked out, leaving his books on the table.

**EDIT**

Given your new information, I think you are introducing unnecessary ambiguity with the two meanings of *left*. It's not clear who is doing the leaving of books, or if nobody is, as *left* can be used with or without an object. After your edits I would recast the sentence a different way:

> He walked out; Rachel's books remained on the table.

or

> He walked out; Rachel's books stayed on the table.

Comment: @crypto: The early bird catches the bacon and eggs.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, but what I stressed on is the grammar. I've changed the sentences.

Answer (score 3):

They are still awkward after your edit, and Robusto's adjustment would be to

> He walked out, leaving Rachel's books on the table.

Other possibilities include

> He walked out; Rachel's books were left on the table.

or perhaps

> He walked out, with Rachel's books (being) left on the table.

Comment: aha, the last one is what I'm looking for, and my question was whether using "being" or not make any difference?

Comment: In the last, *being* doen't make much difference; including it may slightly increase the suggestion that *he* did not pick the books up. But I think the earlier two suggestions flow better.

Answer (score 2):

Why make it so complicated?  Write:

> He left Rachel's books on the table and walked out.

Comment: Depends on what one wants to emphasize.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are **absolute constructions**. They are perfectly correct, but in most cases rather literary and old fashioned. I think Jason's explanation of what difference *being* makes is right, though I find it hard to explain why *being* makes a difference here.

The absolute construction is like a regular, attributive participial phrase, except that the agent/subject of the participle is not a noun or pronoun from the main clause but is itself a part of the construction:

> **Provided that she receive no visitors**, she will be allowed to stay at home. *(absolute construction
>   with past participle)*
>
> **Her mother dead**, there was nothing
>   keeping her here. *(w. adjective)*
>
> **Her father dying**, she felt she could
>   not leave the island. *(w. present participle)*

In **attributive phrases**, the participle or adjective is an attribute to a head noun or pronoun outside the participial phrase (**attribute** in bold, *head* in italics):

> **Roughly measured**, *the height of the table* seemed about right.
>
> **Hit hard by the earthquake**, *Japan* will need time to mourn its dead.
>
> **Still wet behind the ears**, *he* assumed
>   she would indeed show him around her
>   bedroom.
>
> **Giving her the ring**, *he* spoke: et nunc moriere!

Both attributive participial phrases and absolute constructions can be anywhere within a sentence:

> There was nothing she could do, **her
>   husband being such a jerk**. *(abs.)*
>
> The King, **his crown (having been)
>   destroyed by the assassin**, had lost his last shred
>   of dignity. *(abs.)*
>
> *Nurse Ursula*, **suffering from a terrible disease**, still managed to
>   cure all patients with her magic
>   touch. *(attributive)*
>
> Nurse Ursula cured *all patients*
>   **suffering from pneumonia** with her magic touch. *(attributive)*

Usually the head of an attributive participle is the subject of the main clause; but not always, as you can see in my second *Nurse Ursula* sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is a participial phrase, but the subject of the first clause is different from the subject of the second clause (which seems to me what my grammar book describes as *dangling participial*).

> Taking the ferry across the harbor, the Statue of Liberty came into view. [dangling participial]
>   Taking the ferry across the harbor, I saw the Statue of Liberty come into view.

The correct sentence is the one already reported by others.

> He walked out, leaving Rachel's books on the table.
>   He walked out, forgetting Rachel's books on the table.

The first sentence is similar to a comma splice. To correct it, you could write it as one of the following sentences.

> He walked out; Rachel's books were left on the table.
>   He walked out; Rachel's books were forgot on the table.

Comment: Are you sure it's wrong? A sentence like "He walked out, tears welling up in his eyes" seems fine to me. (Or the sentences by Jason: "He walked out, Rachel's words [being] indelibly etched into his memory.")